# why it exports: "./pipesocks: No such file or directory"? actually the file pipesocks does exist

Tags: linux

```
root@AR:~# wget https://github.com/pipesocks/pipesocks/releases/download/2.3/pipesocks-2.3-linux.tar.xz
root@AR:~# tar Jxvf pipesocks-2.3-linux.tar.xz
root@AR:~# cd pipesocks
root@AR:~/pipesocks# ls

libQt5Core.so.5     libicui18n.so.56  pipesocks
libQt5Network.so.5  libicuuc.so.56    platforms
libicudata.so.56    libsodium.so.18   runpipesocks.sh

root@AR:~/pipesocks# ./pipesocks
-bash: ./pipesocks: No such file or directory
root@AR:~/pipesocks# cat /etc/issue.net
Debian GNU/Linux 7
root@AR:~/pipesocks#
```

why it exports: "./pipesocks: No such file or directory"? actually the file pipesocks does exist.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a hard to debug problem if you encounter it the first time. Hard because the error message doesn't give you the right name of the actual that was not found. I recommend to run the command with strace

```
strace ./pipesocks
```

and you will realize that the problem is not that the file `./pipesocks` isn't found but that a shared library dependency isn't found by the Linux linker. That's because the current folder is not in the default `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Run:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./pipesocks
```

and it should work as expected.